# Connecting Visual Basic with MS Access

Tags: database, visual-studio, t-sql, ms-access

I'm currently using Visual Studio, that's connected to the DB, to create reports.  Pretty sweet stuff.

Anyways, I want to know how I can get these created reports to appear in Access.

Is there a way I can have the Report info displayed in Access?

Comment: Why not simply build the reports in Access? It has an excellent reporting system.

Comment: That sounds like a plannn...do you know where I can get some more info on this? Since I clearly didn't know I could do this